# Programming the LEGO Mindstorms T-Rex

Tags: mindstorms, programming

I followed the instructions up to the `MoveAbsolute` My Block for the T-rex but I'm not able to link the last connection (Brake at End). Can anyone advise what I might need to change?

Comment: Are you referring to the EV3 T-Rex from [The LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Laboratory](http://www.nostarch.com/ev3lab) or a different robot?

Comment: I'm referring to the EV3 T-Rex from Lego Mindstorms EV3 Laboratory from Daniele Benedettelli.